# ADX/KQL - Force column order

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Good day everyone,

I am trying to avoid the automatic reordering of the columns during an **evaluate pivot** operation. Please review below.

I can't force the order with project-reorder because the columns may vary, you can test what I mean by uncommenting the first line and commenting the second line.

I see 2 possible solutions:

- Allow to force the order by providing the schema order in the pivot operator
- Allow to pass a column schema during the project-reorder (the schema must be skipepd if the columns are not available in the table to be reordered).

Am I missing something? If yes, please share your idea.

```
  //let numberFiltersAvailable = 1;
    let numberFiltersAvailable = 2;
    let dataTable = datatable(['Start Date']:string, ['R Ident']:string, ['R Name']:string, ['J Ident']:string, KPI1:string, KPI2:string, KPI3:string, KPI4:string, KPI5:string, ['Sender']:string, ['Receiver']:string, ['J Weight']:string, Duration:string)
    [
        "23-04-28 [22:00]", "R1", "", "001900", "46.6 %", "46.16 %", "100.0 %", "73.36 %", "63.52 %", "S1", "Re1", "2 tons", "53min", 
        "23-04-29 [05:24]", "R2", "", "001898", "59.96 %", "59.96 %", "98.19 %", "85.55 %", "71.38 %", "S1", "Re1", "1 tons", "04h, 36min", 
        "23-04-29 [10:00]", "R3", "", "001901", "57.62 %", "57.62 %", "97.89 %", "92.44 %", "63.68 %", "S1", "Re1", "6 tons", "01h, 59min", 
        "23-04-29 [11:59]", "R3", "", "001902", "50.72 %", "50.72 %", "100.0 %", "80.91 %", "62.69 %", "S1", "Re1", "6 tons", "02h, 09min", 
        "23-04-29 [14:09]", "R4", "", "001903", "0.0 %", "0.0 %", "100.0 %", "84.39 %", "0.0 %", "S1", "Re1", "5 tons", "01h, 46min", 
        "23-04-29 [15:55]", "R2", "", "001904", "68.95 %", "68.95 %", "93.96 %", "93.26 %", "78.69 %", "S1", "Re1", "1 tons", "06h, 04min", 
    ];
    let empty_calculationValue = view(){
        dataTable
        | take 1
        | project Value = "Please select a filter",
                  Validation = case(numberFiltersAvailable > 1, 1, 0)
        };
    dataTable
        | extend Validation = case(numberFiltersAvailable > 1, 0, 1)
        | as t1
        | union kind=outer (empty_calculationValue)
        | where Validation == 1
        | project-away Validation 
        | evaluate narrow()
        | where isnotempty(Value)
        | extend Column = replace_string(replace_string(replace_string(Column, "[", ""), "'", ""), "]", "")
        | evaluate pivot(Column, take_any(Value), Row)
        | project-away Row
```

Comment: Hm, smells a bit like an X-Y problem - I assume the main point is that you want to rename columns by removing `[`, `]` and `'` from the names (which in this particular example doesn't do anything since your column names don't include any of these characters)?
Is the total set of columns fixed or are these column names dynamically generated by some data source?

Comment: But in general - no you cannot define a custom order since the pivot plugin sorts the columns alphabetically and that is not configurable. Maybe you can use `project-rename` together with the `has` operator to check if the column exists. This only works if the total set of column names is known upfront obviously

Comment: The line to rename parenthesis is obsolete for this table. I used for the actual data, this sample data does not require that line. Unfortunately, the column names are dynamically defined and the header names are unknown until execution.

Comment: I think the bad new is that you cannot do this with KQL built-in stuff. You may be able to do this with the python plugin if your data set is not too large and if you're allowed to use the python plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As `pivot` plugin rotates a table by turning the unique values from one column in the input table into multiple columns in the output table and performs aggregations as required on any remaining column values that will appear in the final output. And then it performs a *default sorting in ascending order* on columns. To read more about pivot please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin).

If column is not there in the table, after doing the `pivot` on a particular column there will not be any rows pertaining to the column.

To perform customized sorting, one must aware about table schema or the columns available for the table.